# Close opened element and show the new clicked one

Tags: javascript, html

sorry in advance I'm not sure how to explain this but I'll try.

I do have a div #email-display that shows information about an email received on a new single page.
it works fine until here, but when I go back without refreshing the page And click to open another email, it shows me the 2 emails in the same div the old opened one and the one I just opened, how can I only open and show 1 at a time in the page?

Is it possible to reset all appended divs in the email display Div and then show the new appended ones only?

A function to load mailbox then refers to another function on click

```
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#email-display').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
    fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`) // url with that API
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(emails => {
        // Print emails
        console.log(emails); // all emails as objects
        // Loop and show all the emails in that mailbox.
        emails.forEach(function(email) { // loop to loop over each object
            const element = document.createElement('div'); // make new div element for each object (email)
              if (email.read == false){
                element.style.background = 'white';
              }else{
                element.style.background = 'gray';
              }
              element.classList.add('element');
              element.innerHTML = email.sender + email.subject + email.timestamp
              document.querySelector('#emails-view').append(element);
              element.addEventListener('click', function() {
                display_email(email) ****# here it goes to open the email in new page.****
              });
        });
    });
  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
}
```

A function that opens the new page with the email that was clicked on

```
function display_email(email_to_open){
    document.querySelector('#email-display').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
    fetch(`/emails/${email_to_open.id}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(email_to_open => {
        // Print email
        console.log(email_to_open);

        // show the email clicked on page.
        const email_from = document.createElement('div');
        const email_to = document.createElement('div');
        const email_subject = document.createElement('div');
        const email_timestamp = document.createElement('div');
        const email_body = document.createElement('div');
        const archive_button = document.createElement('div');

        email_from.innerHTML = 'From: ' + email_to_open.sender
        email_to.innerHTML =    'To: ' + email_to_open.recipients
        email_subject.innerHTML ='Subject: ' +  email_to_open.subject
        email_timestamp.innerHTML = 'Timestamp: ' +email_to_open.timestamp
        email_body.innerHTML = email_to_open.body

        document.querySelector('#email-display').appendChild(email_from)
        document.querySelector('#email-display').appendChild(email_to)
        document.querySelector('#email-display').appendChild(email_subject)
        document.querySelector('#email-display').appendChild(email_timestamp)
        document.querySelector('#email-display').appendChild(email_body)

        if (email_to_open.archived == false){
            archive_button.innerHTML = `<button class="Archive">Archive</button>`
        }
        else{
            archive_button.innerHTML = `<button class="UnArchive">UnArchive</button>`
        }
        archive_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (archive_button.innerHTML == `<button class="Archive">Archive</button>`) {
                fetch(`/emails/${email_to_open.id}`, {
                  method: 'PUT',
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                      archived: true
                  })
                })
                archive_button.innerHTML = `<button class="UnArchive">UnArchive</button>`
            }else{
                fetch(`/emails/${email_to_open.id}`, {
                  method: 'PUT',
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                      archived: false
                  })
                })
                archive_button.innerHTML = `<button class="Archive">Archive</button>`
            }
        });
            document.querySelector('#email-display').appendChild(archive_button)
        });
        // and mark email as read.
        fetch(`/emails/${email_to_open.id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
          read: true
            })
        })
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="emails-view">

</div>

<div id="email-display">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reset it with

```
document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = "";
```

Or instead of creating and appending a new `DIV` each time, simply insert the data directly into `#emails-view`